# understanding msaccess query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

from the following query can you guys pick what sort of table and table columns is being used ? i'm new to ms access its quite confusing, i have had a look, is it the following 
table/columns being used?

Tables Name ||  table columns 
com020          (.t_nama,.t_namb)
mcs031          (.t_suno,.t_dsca)

And RIGHT JOIN on column t_cbrn in table com020.

And  don't understand why & ContryCode & is being using all the time.

```
Sub VSearch(Letter,Name,Vcode,LPage,CurrentPage)
dim countryCode
countryCode = readfromRegistry("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\HR\DSN\mkCountryCode")

dim oRs2,Query2,i,colourcount
Set oRs2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Query2 = "SELECT com020" & countryCode & ".t_nama, com020" & countryCode & ".t_namb,  ttccom020" 
& countryCode & ".t_suno, mcs031" & countryCode & ".t_dsca FROM mcs031" & countryCode
& " RIGHT JOIN com020" & countryCode & " ON mcs031" & countryCode & ".t_cbrn = com020" &   countryCode & ".t_cbrn "

if letter <> "" then
Query2 = Query2 & "WHERE (com020" & countryCode & ".t_nama) Like '" & QueryFix(Letter) &     "%'  escape '\' ORDER BY com020" & countryCode & ".t_nama"
elseif name <> "" then
Query2 = Query2 & "WHERE LOWERCASE((com020" & countryCode & ".t_nama)) Like '%" &  LCase(Name) & "%' ORDER BY com020" & countryCode & ".t_nama"
elseif Vcode <> "" then
Query2 = Query2 & "WHERE (com020" & countryCode & ".t_suno) Like '%" & UCase(Vcode) & "%'  ORDER BY com020" & countryCode & ".t_nama"
elseif LPage <> "" then
Query2 = Query2 & "WHERE (com020" & countryCode & ".t_cbrn) = '" & LPage & "' ORDER BY com020" & countryCode & ".t_nama"
end if
```

Comment: The columns are **t_nama**, **t_namb**, **t_suno**, **t_dsca**

However all your tables are named with the countryCode, e.g. if the CountryCode is **ABC**, your tables name would be **msc031ABC**, **com020ABC**

Comment: Thanks Nick! i understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

The countryCode is used to form an add-hock query in the event you have variable tables used in the database. This way the query does not have to be updated to handle each table.

The names of the columns are:
t_nama
t_namb
t_suno
t_dsca

I find it useful to break view in debug mode at the point the query is created and copy the variable holding the SQL into your 'immediate' window to see the result of the query after it has been formed.